# Python Pandas, make date time rounding based on value in another column

Tags: python, data-mining, pandas, time

I am trying to round the timestamp of sensor data on the nearest 5 minutes based on the type of sensor. I have a column called 'sensor type' with two options: 'air' or 'sound'. For sensor type air the timestamp should be rounded to the nearest 5 minutes. The timestamp of sensor type sound should stay the same.

With this rule all timestamps are rounded to 5 min, which works.

`df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.round('5min')`

With the mask below all sensor types for air are selected.

`mask = df['sensor type'] == 'air'`

Actually I should combine both rules to get what I want. However, I am not able to manage how this works. 
The rule below gives an error "TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column".

`mask = df.loc[df['sensor type'] == 'air']`

`df[‘timestamp’][mask] = df[‘timestamp'][mask].dt.round('5min')`

```
dtypes:
timestamp        datetime64[ns]
sensor type              object
```

I hope someone can help me how I could combine both lines,

Comment: Hello, some data to reproduce the error would be nice please.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['2020-04-14 00:00:23', '2020-04-14 00:00:37', '2020-04-14 00:01:01', 
                                        '2020-04-14 00:01:05', '2020-04-14 00:01:19'], 
                'sensor type' : ['sound', 'air', 'sound', 'air', 'sound']})

Comment: I added an answer please check if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to earlier answer you can also try below-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['2020-04-14 00:00:23', '2020-04-14 00:00:37', '2020-04-14 00:01:01', '2020-04-14 00:01:05', '2020-04-14 00:01:19'], 'sensor' : ['sound', 'air', 'sound', 'air', 'sound']})

df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df
```

> ```
> mask = df['sensor'] == 'air'
> df.loc[mask, 'timestamp'] = df.loc[mask, 'timestamp'].dt.round('5min')
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

given you want to do something perhaps a little different for each `sensor type`, you could group them together, using [**`groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Given your example data, the following rounds the timestamps all to the nearest *5 second* timestamp (seconds show the result better than minutes for your example):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['2020-04-14 00:00:23', '2020-04-14 00:00:37',
                                          '2020-04-14 00:01:01', '2020-04-14 00:01:05',
                                          '2020-04-14 00:01:19'],
                           'sensor type' : ['sound', 'air', 'sound', 'air', 'sound']})
```

Convert the timestamp to an actual timestamp type (it was a string by default):

```
In [3]: df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
```

`Groupby` sensor types and perform the rounding method on each sub-dataframe, putting the result into a new column in the original dataframe:

```
In [4]: df["rounded_timestamp"] = df.groupby("sensor type").transform(lambda d: d.dt.round("5s"))
```

If you want to do very specific things on each sub-dataframe, you can implement a small function instead of using the anonymous lambda function.

Notice the rounded values from the `timestamp` to the `rounded_timestamp` column:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
            timestamp sensor type   rounded_timestamp
0 2020-04-14 00:00:23       sound 2020-04-14 00:00:25
1 2020-04-14 00:00:37         air 2020-04-14 00:00:35
2 2020-04-14 00:01:01       sound 2020-04-14 00:01:00
3 2020-04-14 00:01:05         air 2020-04-14 00:01:05
4 2020-04-14 00:01:19       sound 2020-04-14 00:01:20
```

---

I assume you might have or create other columns now too, so I would usually also make the index of the dataframe the most important timestamp for your use case, because then you get access to some powerful attributes and methods of the [**`pd.DateTimeIndex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
In [6]: df.set_index("rounded_timestamp", drop=True, inplace=True)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                                timestamp sensor type
rounded_timestamp                                  
2020-04-14 00:00:25   2020-04-14 00:00:23       sound
2020-04-14 00:00:35   2020-04-14 00:00:37         air
2020-04-14 00:01:00   2020-04-14 00:01:01       sound
2020-04-14 00:01:05   2020-04-14 00:01:05         air
2020-04-14 00:01:20   2020-04-14 00:01:19       sound
```

Comment: Thank you n1k31t4 for your comprehensive explanation. However, you refer to a small function or an anonymous lambda function for the application to sound or air sensors in specific. This is actually exactly what I do not get, how to do this?